# What is maximum size of a txt file to process in power query? removing top rows function not processing for a long time

Tags: ms-office, powerquery, excel-2016

What is maximum size of a txt file to process in power query? I'm trying to remove top 5400 rows from a sorted data. The txt file size 3.67 GB and total number of records are around 9.4 Million. I waited for almost 45 mins but didn't processed by the system. My system RAM is 8 GB. What might be the reason for this and how can overcome this?

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: Is the input already sorted on import, or are you sorting it in PowerQuery M, then removing rows? M is good at importing data, but not complex processing on large amounts of data -- that's something for DAX to do when the data is there. First just try importing the rows without any processing beyond parsing the text, and see how long that takes. It'll probably still be a while, but it shouldn't be 45 minutes unless your disk is very slow.

Comment: No the input data which was imported is not sorted. I imported the data of 94 lakh records comprising  3.68 GB TXT file into power querry and didn't took much (approx 2 to mins). Then I sorted the data in power querry. This task was also completed in 2 to 3 mins. But deleting top 5400 rows which are headings is not been processed. I tried thrice and left the process

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.